Onnx inference differs from Pytorch inference
I trained a custom PyTorch model and it's showing good results, when I exported it to onnx and tried to inference, I got absolutely different results on the same data I pushed to PyTorch.
Here is the code PyTorch side:
*** Parameters ***
normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                 std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])

data_transforms = {
    'train':
    transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomAffine(0, shear=10, scale=(0.8,1.2)),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        normalize
    ]),
    'validation':
    transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        normalize
    ]),
}

*** ResNet model ***
model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True).to(device)
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False   
model.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(512, 4)).to(device)

*** Here I'm saving my model ***
model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
torch.save(model, OUT_DIR + 'best.pt')
torch.save(model.state_dict(), OUT_DIR + 'best_dict.pt')
traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model, torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224).cuda())
torch.jit.save(traced_model, OUT_DIR + "best_traced.pt")

*** Evaluating ***
Output for 1 image --> [-2.0991, -0.8286, -2.8393, -1.5794]

Here is the code onnx side:
*** Exporting to ONNX ***
mg_dim = (224, 224, 3)
rgb_mean = (104, 117, 123)  # bgr order
num_classes = 4
model_path = "./resnet_runs/train/exp5/best_dict.pt"
onnx_path = "resnet18.onnx"

*** Create the model and load the weights ***
model = models.resnet18(pretrained=False)
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False  

model.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(512, num_classes))

state_dict = torch.load(model_path)

model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
model.eval()

# Create dummy input
dummy_input = torch.rand(1, 3, img_dim[0], img_dim[1]).float()

# Define input / output names
input_names = ["input"]
output_names = ["output"]

# Convert the PyTorch model to ONNX
torch.onnx.export(model,
                  dummy_input,
                  onnx_path,
                  verbose=True,
                  input_names=input_names,
                  output_names=output_names)

*** Evaluating ***
Output for the same image --> [  1.9905291,  -1.6136904, -96.301994 , -41.041725 ]

For the inference I'm using onnxrt.InferenceSession
I tried a lot, I watched different posts, tried different ways of saving onnx, but nothing is useful, I had an idea that something with transforms for PyTorch weights, but I'm not sure.
If anybody have an answer, I would be very happy to hear it.

Your code shows you using a random input in each test. Why would you expect different random inputs to give the same result?
